# C# Winform: Print ListView Contents

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, printing

Can someone show me how to print the ListView contents with the ColumnHeaders, without the scrollbars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [ListViewPrinter](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ListViewPrinter.aspx) and the update that is part of [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx).

It prints a ListView, as well as providing print preview. Even if you don't use the whole project, you can at least see how it is done.

[image]